# How to extract time from timestamp?

Tags: php, sql

I have extract date from timestamp but how to I extract time from timestamp? I had doing some research but I can found it. Can someone help me work out from this?

This is my sql code:

```
$stmt = "SELECT id, date(creation_timestamp) as date, time(creation_timestap) as time, text FROM "._CONST_TBL_COMMUNITY_COMMENT;
            
            if($rs = $db->Execute($stmt))
            {
                while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow())
                {
                    array_push($arrResult, array(
                    "id" => $rsa['id'],
                    "date" => $rsa['date'],
                    "time" => $rsa['time'],
                    "text" => $rsa['text']
                    ));
                }
            }
```

And this is my result which without **`time(creation_timestamp) as time`** in above sql statement:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [date] => 2014-05-14 [text] => test test test test )
```

Comment: What is the type of the `creation_timestamp` field in the database? Possible to share schema?

Comment: And what result getting including time query ?

Comment: and what is *with* time(creation_timestamp) as time?

Comment: it return nothing. RESULT : ARRAY()

Comment: I'm surprised `as date` works, considering `date` is a reserved word and must be in backticks...

Comment: Can you please add error checking to your code and determine whether the query failed? The exact generated SQL code (as opposed to the PHP source code) would also help.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - It seems to work anyway. In fact, I can run `SELECT date(current_timestamp) as date, time(current_timestamp) as time` flawlessly in my 5.5 server.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Hrm. I guess maybe MySQL is clever enough to know that `AS` expects an alias name and therefore assumes it even if you put a keyword there?

Comment: Most likely, yep. Because as column name it must be escaped for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't look at your PHP code. In standard SQL, you can cast a timestamp as time.

```
select cast(current_timestamp as time) as just_time . . .
```

Comment: ops. It works. Just now is my mistake, I forget to put ',' in mysql.

Comment: FYI, [TIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function used in the question should work as well.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Depends on your dbms. For example, time() won't work on SQL Server, PostgreSQL, or Oracle.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I hadn't noticed the question tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you work directly with PHP you can just submit the Timestamp:

```
$time=date("H:i",$timestamp);
$date=date("d.m.Y",$timestamp);
$datezime=date("d.m.Y H:i",$timestmap);
```

For more information: [Date (PHP Docs)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php)

For SQL: [from_unixtime (mySQL Docs)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

You can then use it like this:

```
from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guy. I found my mistake. I write wrong for my database filed name which on **`time(creation_timestap) as time`**. It suppose **`time(creation_timestamp) as time`**.
Sorry for my mistake and trouble you guy's time.

Comment: I insist: you don't have to *guess* this kind of things. All database libraries provide error checking features that give you the exact error message returned by the server–but you need to use them!

Comment: Furthermore, `TIME()` is not a standard SQL function.